# MySQL Too Many Connections on Windows -- can't flush-hosts

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1040

I have a MySql install on Windows Server 2008 which has hit its max connections threshold. As such, whenever I try to login to it, I see 'error 1040: too many connections.' I have Administrator access to the Windows server.

I'm unable to login via the MySql Administrator tool, and I am unable to execute commands such as:

```
mysqladmin.exe flush-hosts
```

When I try the above, I simply receive the 'too many connections' error. I have tried specifying the -uroot flag but this doesn't seem to have helped.

As such, I have no idea how to fix this issue. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I found in the net, it looks like you might have to restart the mysql demon (which when you cannot connect with mysqladmin might be a problem in it self, I am not experienced enough to know the best way to shut MySql down in such situations), except you have an admin-account with super privilege. This account should be able to login and do the flush-hosts. But this does not seem to be a default privilege for root, so you would have to grant it before this kind of problem occurs. See this [chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/too-many-connections.html) "C.5.2.7. Too many connections" in the Mysql Reference Manual for more detailed information about this, there is also a hard limit mentioned for windows platforms: (open tables × 2 + open connections) < 2048.

Depending on the system-architecture that uses the database there might be other possibilities - e.g. you might be able to close connections from the client-side by shutting down an application.

Comment: Thanks - I was unable to grant the SUPER privilege without connecting, so that avenue was closed. In the end, I simply waited for a client connection to time out (8 hours) and then was able to run flush-hosts. I still, however, have no idea how to fix the problem aside from waiting 8 hours. I have now granted SUPER privileges to prevent this from happening again.